# open() blocks during opening a fifo

Tags: linux, fifo

```
#define FIFO1       "/tmp/fifo.1"
#define FIFO2       "/tmp/fifo.2"

//#define   FILE_MODE   O_CREAT | O_EXCL
//#define   FILE_MODE   S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH
#define FILE_MODE   0666

int32_t main()
{
    if ((mkfifo(FIFO1, FILE_MODE)  < 0) && (errno != EEXIST))
    {
        cout << "Can't create fifo " << FIFO1 << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    if ((mkfifo(FIFO2, FILE_MODE)  < 0) && (errno != EEXIST))
    {
        cout << "Can't create fifo " << FIFO2 << endl;
        unlink(FIFO1);
        return 2;
    }

    cout << "FIFO created. Now creating child process..." << endl;

    pid_t child_pid = fork();
    if (child_pid == 0)
    {
        cout << "Inside child process..." << endl;

        int32_t read_fd = open(FIFO1, O_RDONLY, 0);
        cout << "[CHILD] Read fd = " << read_fd << endl;
        int32_t write_fd = open(FIFO2, O_WRONLY, 0); 
        cout << "[CHILD] Write fd = " << write_fd << endl;

        child_process(read_fd, write_fd);

        exit(0);
    }

    cout << "Inside parent process..." << endl;

    int32_t read_fd = open(FIFO2, O_RDONLY, 0); 
    cout << "[PARENT] Read fd = " << read_fd << endl;
    int32_t write_fd = open(FIFO1, O_WRONLY, 0);
    cout << "[PARENT] Write fd = " << write_fd << endl;

    parent_process(read_fd, write_fd);

    waitpid(child_pid, 0, 0);

    close(read_fd);
    close(write_fd);

    unlink(FIFO1);
    unlink(FIFO2);

    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, the first open() blocks infinitely for both parent and child process. I tried with all FILE_MODE combinations commented in code but it blocks. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: From `man mkfifo`: "Opening a FIFO for reading normally blocks until some other process opens the same FIFO for writing, and vice versa".  Try opening the FIFOs in the same order in both processes.

Comment: Thanks. I got my mistake.